# I can't unblock the error "Exception: Please select an active sheet first."

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm doing the Fundamentals of Apps Script course by Google and I'm encountering the following error:

"Exception: Please select an active sheet first.
duplicateAndOrganizeActiveSheet @ Code.gs:7"

I've literally just pasted what the instructions said, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. The instructions said to paste the following code and run the function called "duplicateAndOrganizeActiveSheet()" to duplicate the active sheet.

```
    function renameSpreadsheet() {
  var mySS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  mySS.rename("2017 Avocado Prices in Portland, Seattle");
}
function duplicateAndOrganizeActiveSheet() {
  var mySS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var duplicateSheet = mySS.duplicateActiveSheet();
}
```

However, I'm not able to run it because it gives me this error. I've read other posts and tried many things but I can't seem to find what's wrong with the code.

I'd appreciate help unblocking this so I can continue with the course. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and solution:

First, I think that your script has no issue.

From your error message of `"Exception: Please select an active sheet first. duplicateAndOrganizeActiveSheet @ Code.gs:7"`, I thought that in your situation, the link of the container-bound script (I think that in this case, it's script editor.) and Google Spreadsheet might be broken. For example, when such a situation occurs, an error like `Please select an active sheet first.` occurs.

In this case, please close Google Spreadsheet and the script editor. And, please open Google Spreadsheet and open the script editor, and run `duplicateAndOrganizeActiveSheet` again.

If this solution couldn't resolve the issue of `Please select an active sheet first.`, please create a new Google Spreadsheet, open the script editor of the created Google Spreadsheet, please copy and paste your script, and run the script again.

Comment: I was so fixated on "there's something wrong with the code" that I didn't even think it could be something else. Closing and re-opening definitely fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Juan Marín Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.